# join two datasets by subject ID and matching sequence ID in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets that I want to join into a single one:

```
set.seed(111)
dat1 = data.frame(subject = paste0("A-",c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5)), 
                  seq1 = c(2, 3, 7, 8, 2, 9, 11, 10, 11, 16), 
                  text1 = sample(LETTERS, 10))
dat1

   subject seq1 text1
1      A-1    2     P
2      A-1    3     S
3      A-2    7     I
4      A-2    8     L
5      A-3    2     X
6      A-3    9     V
7      A-3   11     A
8      A-4   10     K
9      A-4   11     H
10     A-5   16     B

set.seed(999)
dat2 = data.frame(subject = paste0("A-", c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5)), 
                  seq2 = c(2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 2, 9, 11, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19), 
                  text2 = sample(LETTERS, 13))
dat2
       subject seq2 text2
1      A-1    2     K
2      A-1    3     O
3      A-1    4     C
4      A-2    7     T
5      A-2    8     R
6      A-3    2     X
7      A-3    9     M
8      A-3   11     B
9      A-4   10     H
10     A-5   16     Z
11     A-5   17     E
12     A-5   18     I
13     A-5   19     A
```

Both datasets have the same `subject` as in the first column, but the number of observations for each `subject` may be different (e.g., in `dat1`, subject A-1 has two records (`seq1` has 2 and 3), but in `dat2`, the same subject A-1 has three records (`seq2` has 2, 3 and 4). I'd like the joined dataset to contain all subjects in both datasets, while keeping in the same row a unique sequence number (`seq1` and `seq2`) with the corresponding `text1` and `text2`. Assign `NA` if one dataset is missing one sequence ID but the same sequence ID is found in the other dataset.

The final dataset looks like:

```
#    subject seq1 text1 seq2 text2
# 1      A-1    2     P    2     K
# 2      A-1   NA    NA    4     C
# 3      A-1    3     S    3     O
# 4      A-2    7     I    7     T
# 5      A-2    8     L    8     R
# 6      A-3    2     X    2     X
# 7      A-3    9     V    9     M
# 8      A-3   11     A   11     B
# 9      A-4   10     K   10     H
# 10     A-4   11     H   NA     NA
# 11     A-5   16     B   16     Z
# 12     A-5   17     E   NA     NA
# 13     A-5   18     I   NA     NA
# 14     A-5   19     A   NA     NA
```

As you see, the joined dataset has the same `seq1` and `seq2` for the same `subject`, and in case of a missing sequence ID (either in `seq1` or `seq2`), an `NA` is assigned. Thank you for your suggestions in utilizing `dplyr` for this task!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a new column in each data set called seq and then used a full_join

```
full_join(mutate(dat1, seq = seq1),
          mutate(dat2, seq = seq2)) %>% 
  arrange(subject, seq) %>% 
  select(-seq)
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(111)
dat1 = tibble(subject = paste0("A-",c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5)), 
                  seq1 = c(2, 3, 7, 8, 2, 9, 11, 10, 11, 16), 
                  text1 = sample(LETTERS, 10))
dat1

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    subject  seq1 text1
#>      <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1     A-1     2     P
#>  2     A-1     3     S
#>  3     A-2     7     I
#>  4     A-2     8     L
#>  5     A-3     2     X
#>  6     A-3     9     V
#>  7     A-3    11     A
#>  8     A-4    10     K
#>  9     A-4    11     H
#> 10     A-5    16     B


set.seed(999)
dat2 = tibble(subject = paste0("A-", c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5)), 
                  seq2 = c(2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 2, 9, 11, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19), 
                  text2 = sample(LETTERS, 13))


dat1 <- dat1 %>% mutate(id = seq1)
dat2 <- dat2 %>% mutate(id = seq2)


dat1 %>% 
  full_join(dat2, by = c("subject", "id")) %>% 
  arrange(subject, id) %>% 
  select(-id)

#> # A tibble: 14 x 5
#>    subject  seq1 text1  seq2 text2
#>      <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1     A-1     2     P     2     K
#>  2     A-1     3     S     3     O
#>  3     A-1    NA  <NA>     4     C
#>  4     A-2     7     I     7     T
#>  5     A-2     8     L     8     R
#>  6     A-3     2     X     2     X
#>  7     A-3     9     V     9     M
#>  8     A-3    11     A    11     B
#>  9     A-4    10     K    10     H
#> 10     A-4    11     H    NA  <NA>
#> 11     A-5    16     B    16     Z
#> 12     A-5    NA  <NA>    17     E
#> 13     A-5    NA  <NA>    18     I
#> 14     A-5    NA  <NA>    19     A
```